# Why does default parameter value not work?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I have a function which grabs some stuff from a database. I want to set the function to accept a `DBConnection` string parameter and a `ProductID` parameter, but because this will rarely be provided I would like a set a default value. I tried the following:

```
const DBConfig = require('./db.config');
async function getProduct(DBConnection = DBConfig.SQLConnection, ProductID) {
    console.log(ProductID)       // says undefined
    await DBConnection.connect()
......
}
```

I call the above function from another file by doing this:

```
Product = await api.getProduct({ProductID: req.body.ProductID})
```

For some reason,  doing the above does not work. That is, I always get `undefined` in the console for `ProductID`.

If I simply do the following, then I do get the correct `ProductID` value printing in the console:

```
const DBConfig = require('./db.config');
const DBConnection = DBConfig.SQLConnection,
async function getProduct(ProductID) {
        console.log(ProductID)       // prints in the console as { ProductID: '1234' }
        await DBConnection.connect()
    ......
    }
```

I am using Webpack with babel-loader. I don't *think* it is a transpilation issue but not sure. Any ideas? In my Webpack config I have this to handle `js` files:

```
 {
      test: /\.js$/,
        include: [ srcPath ],
      exclude: ['/node_modules/','/src/test'],
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]  //Preset used for env setup
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Parameters with defaults have to be after parameters without defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the parameters of `getProduct` to be destructured:

```js
function getProduct({DBConnection = DBConfig.SQLConnection, ProductID}) {
    ...
}
```

Then you can do:

```js
Product = await api.getProduct({ProductID: req.body.ProductID})
```

Shouldn't be a webpack or babel issue

Comment: I think you have the right idea, but that's not the correct syntax for providing a default in a destructured argument.

Comment: `function getProduct({DBConnection = DBConfig.SQLConnection, ProductID}) { ... }`